# Liquid error: Error - Illegal template path

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, liquid, dotliquid, liquid-template

I am facing this issue in c# code. While using liquid templates `include` formula.

```cs
string liquidTemplateContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("wwwroot/template/example.liquid");
LocalFileSystem fileSys = new DotLiquid.FileSystems.LocalFileSystem("wwwroot\\template");
Template.FileSystem = fileSys;
Template template = Template.Parse(liquidTemplateContent);
```

In following liquid file for `{% include  'function' -%}` this part, I'm facing this issue. Whenever the path coming under the error is valid path
And that _function.liquid file is also present over there.

> error with path: **Liquid error: Error - Illegal template path 'D:\Include Trial1\DotLiquidTest\wwwroot\template\_function.liquid**'

```
<p>
  Email: {{ employee.email }}
</p>
<p>
  Phone: {{ employee.phone }}
</p>
<p>Addresses:</p>
<div>
  {% include  'function' -%}
</div>
```

I am not sure what is missing here. I am using dotliquid NuGet package for the same.